# Should i use html5 in my new work?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Should i use html5 in my new project? I don't know what will be the problem. What will happen with MSIE ? Will this be supported in older version of IE? and what are the things I need to keep in mind ?

I searched but couldn't find a good answer.

Comment: http://diveintohtml5.info/introduction.html

Comment: thanks guys. i'm gonna use html5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the functionalities you will need, if you need functionalities from html5 then use it, but be sure to do the progressive enhancement, this means, make sure something work for older browsers, and upgrade those functionalities to html5 so it works on both.

For the basic tags backward compatibility you can use this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src=\"http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js\"></script><![endif]-->
```

It's a script that replaces the new html5 tags with old ones so you don't have to worry too much about it.

Anyway the most important parts resides in the javascript and css, so for example if you do a link that on click it makes an ajax call, normally you would do:

```
$('.miLink').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();//this avoid the link to change to another page
    $.ajax(..... // ajax request;
});
```

So the natural thing for progressive enhancement is to let that link redirect to a page for the login system the old way for example, and add the Jquery/javascript functionality so if the browser support it, still does the ajax request. This way you got a link that work on both new and old browsers.

for the CSS you can also always include rules that work for new browsers, and include special rules with the conditional comments to override the ones before, therefore working for old browsers.

For my new project I used html5 and from my experience the users are coming with not-so-old browsers, and the old browsers users are decreasing day by day statisticly.

Also I support the idea of advancing technologically and get the users used to use the latest technologies so the webdeveloping is not stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep in mind that some features won't work on old browsers, but make it work well on those old browsers and make it look awesome in new browsers! HTML5 and CSS3 is the 'NOW' and if you want to develop for web you must know it and start using it to help the web to grow together. Get old versions of HTML will work, but it's not helping the internet to get this one step ahead

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 in your new project. for the most part its backwards compatible, if you use the new HTML5 features you can use a javascript polyfill to give the old browsers the functionality or fail gracefully.

see here for more information: http://www.netmagazine.com/features/making-html5-and-css3-work-polyfills-and-shims